# Python unicode works in 2.6.1 on OSX, but not in 2.6.5 on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, macos, unicode, ubuntu

Given the following code run from the Python interpreter:

```
import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding()
my_string = '\xc3\xa9'
my_string = unicode(my_string, 'utf-8')
my_string
print my_string
```

With Python 2.6.1 running on a mac, everything works fine:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
>>> my_string = '\xc3\xa9'
>>> my_string = unicode(my_string, 'utf-8')
>>> my_string
u'\xe9'
>>> print my_string
é
>>>
```

With Python 2.6.5 running on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, it fails:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
>>> my_string = '\xc3\xa9'
>>> my_string = unicode(my_string, 'utf-8')
>>> my_string
u'\xe9'
>>> print my_string
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

Has something changed between Python 2.6.1 and 2.6.5 that requires different handling of unicode strings? Or does this have to do with something misconfigured in my (default Ubuntu server 10.04 LTS) linux environment?

Edit: Both environments have LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Funny story, though the question was about `Python Unicorn`

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using under Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm using ssh from the terminal in my mac. The server is headless, running on Rackspace, and I installed it with minimal stuff (basically apache and pylons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the error with the command:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=ascii python -c'print "\xc3\xa9".decode("utf-8")'
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 0:\
ordinal not in range(128)
```

[`sys.getdefaultencoding()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys.html#sys.getdefaultencoding) is `'ascii'` and not very useful by default.

Try using your console encoding:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python -c'print "\xc3\xa9".decode("utf-8")'
é
```

or

```
$ python -c'import locale; print "\xc3\xa9".decode("utf-8").encode(
> locale.getpreferredencoding())'
é
```

Check `sys.stdout.encoding`:

```
$ python -c'import sys; o = sys.stdout; print o.isatty(), o.encoding'
True UTF-8

$ python -c'import sys; o = sys.stdout; print o.isatty(), o.encoding' | cat
False None

$ python -c'import sys; o = sys.stdout; print o.isatty(), o.encoding' >/tmp/out
$ cat /tmp/out
False None
```

If `sys.stdout.encoding` is `None` try to use [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) or set [`PYTHONIOENCODING`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) as shown above. See http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails

If the error occurs only in the interactive Python session then look at [`sys.displayhook()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook).

Comment: PYTHONENCODING did the trick. But now, how do I fix the terminal in ubuntu? This is a mini-library whose components will be called via shell commands and via a cronjob script. The messed up terminal is basically an ssh session from my mac (which works) into a headless ubuntu server (which doesn't work unless I set the environment variable). I'd thought that ubuntu was unicode by default, and LANG is en_US.UTF-8 already.

Comment: Never mind. The default ubuntu install doesn't have /etc/default/locale. Once I created that with en_US.UTF-8 it worked.

Answer (score 4):

It can happen with C locale.  Try running Python with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 python` and trying your code again.

Comment: +1, Also, a non-unicode locale can only be excused by really special circumstances.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry forgot to mention that. Both environments have LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried prefixing your string with u?

> my_string = u'\xc3\xa9'

See http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code

> In Python source code, Unicode
>   literals are written as strings
>   prefixed with the ‘u’ or ‘U’
>   character: u'abcdefghijk'. Specific
>   code points can be written using the
>   \u escape sequence, which is followed
>   by four hex digits giving the code
>   point. The \U escape sequence is
>   similar, but expects 8 hex digits, not
>   4.

Comment: Not this, because an encoded bytestring (which is subsequently decoded) is what is desired.

Answer (score 0):

- **Python 3.6.8 or newer**

As @jfs answered,

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python file.py
```

worked for me. And if you want to make it default you can add following command to your `basrc` or `zshrc`

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING="utf-8"
```